# Ionic framework (angular) url convert

Tags: angularjs, url, ionic-framework

I have problem with my ionic app.
My application connect to server via $.http (GET or POST). When script success download data, I display it on

{{data.description}}

My problem is when data.description have url's. When in my db description have link

---

edit

When I use this method:

```
.success(function(data){
  // data.description = test(data.description);
  $scope.task = data;
  $rootScope.MyData = {
    description : '<a href="http://google.com"> dasd</a>' 
  }
})
```

or

```
 $scope.task = data;
      $rootScope.MyData = {
        description : data.description 
      }
```

and in html:

```
 {{MyData.description}}
```

I still have this problem:
[image]

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 1):

Use $rootScope

```
$http.get(...).then(function (response) {
    $rootScope.MyData = {
        description : data.description
    }
}, function (response) {

);
```

Your Html

```
<a class="button button-clear button-positive" 
href="{{MyData.description}}">dasd</a>
```

Note: MyData.description = http://google.com

Comment: I try to use it and I still have problem, If you can plase see edit :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because Angular escapes the html that's within the curly brackets. You can use [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) in combination with [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive. So your code would be like:

```
<p ng-bind-html="MyData.description"></p>
```

Don't use an `<a>` tag for this because the directive will place the html inside whatever tag you use.